# Pytorch / Numpy dimensions math: Why [n] + [n, 1] = [n, n]

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I'm trying to understand the logic for inferring the sematics of addition in numpy/torch. Here is an example that caused a bug in my program:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(2)     # shape (2,)
y = x.reshape(-1, 1) # shape (2, 1)
z = y + x            # expected (2,) or (2, 1)
print(z.shape)       # (2, 2)
```

So basically reshape happened in unrelated operation, however `x` and `y` still had same number of elements, and I've expected to get resulting shape either [2,] or [2, 1] as the addition happens on the axis where all elements live.

My questions:

1. why do I get [2,2] shape?
2. What's bigger picture behind it that can help expect this outcome in similar, but different scenarios?

Comment: This is called [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and happens when operating with tensors/arrays where some dimensions are singletons.

Comment: In a numpy array, `elements` are stored in a 1d data-buffer.  Since `y` is a view of `x`, it uses the same buffer.  It's not a good idea to think of elements "living" in a particular axis.  `shape` controls how those elements are processed.  Anyways, when `broadcasting`, it first matches the number of dimensions, then tries to match the size.  You missed the first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), where the following example is given:

```
x  = np.arange(4)   # shape (4,)
xx = x.reshape(4,1) # shape (4,1)
y  = np.ones(5)     # shape (5,)   

x + y  # ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (5,)
xx + y  # shape (4, 5)
```

"When either of the dimensions compared is **1**, the other is used. In other words, dimensions with size **1** are stretched or “copied” to match the other."

Comment: It would be more appropriate to say they are "expanded" rather than "copied". Indeed a broadcast is a view of the data, not a copy.

Comment: This quoted sentence is extracted from the numpy broadcasting documentation

Comment: Regardless of the source, it is not the correct wording. This will matter in terms of performance.

Comment: Perhaps more important in this question is the first rule - adding leading dimensions to match the total number.  The (5,) is promoted to (1,5).

Comment: @Ivan, the *dimensions* are "copied", not the *values*.  A **1** can be "expanded" to 0.  I'm inclined to use "scaled" instead.